# vmware disk becomes read-only on linux guest

Tags: linux, virtualization, vmware-workstation

I have Linux CentOS as guest OS on VMWare Workstation, the host is Windows Home.

The Disk becomes read-only, every-time i untar a huge file (which results in hundreds of small files) somewhere in the file system on the VM.

What could be causing this? 
Is it because the linux vm guest sees a very huge number of files getting created quickly (as a result of the untar ), and it cannot keep up for some reason and then switches to Read-Only?

I can replicate this issue every-time.
What could be done to solve this.

Comment: What VMware product are you using?  You've tagged this with both server and workstation?

Comment: Shane> I'v corrected the tags. The product is VMware-workstation.

Comment: This can be caused by a know bug,  file systems may become read-only after encountering busy I/O retry or SAN or iSCSI path failover errors. 
You cant try to remount File system by 
mount -o remount /
Please refer to https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2001611

Answer (score 1):

Linux will remount it's partitions in r/o mode to avoid data corruption, if it encounters unstable disk performance (`EIO` errors). Check the underlying storage and the disk image settings.

Comment: dyasny> i have added more relevant details to the question now (sorry, shud have done that upfront) - the underlying host is simply a desktop  with windows home os.

Comment: well, my reply stands - you have a disk access problem. Try to use a separate disk for the VM, or get a faster disk (or set up RAID). There might also be tweaks in VMW WS that will provide better disk performance, but I'm not familiar enough with the product